# Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null - can I force it using an "if" statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm clearly a total beginner. I have 2 html pages that both call the same JavaScript file. The functionality of the JS is to hide certain list items from an unordered list. One of the pages does not have the class that is being called (that div does not exist on the page), so I'm assuming when the JS sees that that particular element is not there, it's throwing the null error, which makes sense to me. Is there a way, using an "if" statement perhaps, that I can fix this? In other words, if this html element is not there, do this anyway?

```
<script>
function opNotices() {

    var list = document.getElementById("op-notices-1").getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].style.display = "none";
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].style.display = "none";

    var list = document.getElementById("op-notices-2").getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[2].style.display = "none";
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[3].style.display = "none";
}

opNotices();
</script>

<html>
 <div id="op-notices-2"><!--#include virtual="content.html" --> 
      </div>
    </html>
```

content.html is:

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
</ul>
```

Output is:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- f

But I want c and d hidden.

Comment: You need to show the code, expected output and the error

Comment: The result of `getElementsByClassName` will have a `.length` that will be > 0 if results are found

Comment: Simple question; when the something you are expecting is null, is this an error (you did something wrong) or an expected situation (it is correct that the thing does not exist). In the case of document.getElementsByClassName, its possible your code has a mistake.

Comment: It's expected behavior, as the "op-notices-1" is not on this page - but it exists on the other page that also calls this JS. So everything works fine on the page with both op-notices-1 and op-notices-2 on it, but when op-notices-1 isn't on the page, I get the null error, which I understand. But I want the JS to function regardless of whether or not that div is on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null" error does not mean that the classname is missing - it means that the thing that you are trying to run 'getElementsByClassName' against does not exist. In other words, your code doesn't get far enough to even try searching for elements by class name.

Specifically, when your code gets to a line like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("op-notices-1").getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
```

it performs the following steps:

1. Get whatever value is stored in the variable name `document`. Since you haven't set it to anything else, it will get back the HTML document, as you expect.
2. Take the value gotten in step 1, and look for a property called `getElementById`. This step only works if the value from step 1 is an `object` (i.e. a set of properties like `{ foo: 1; bar: "2" }`). Since `document` is an object, this works just fine, and gets back the function named `getElementById`.
3. Call the value gotten in step 2 with the arguments `("op-notices-1")`. This only works if the value from step 2 is a `function`. Since it is, it calls the function, and returns the result of `null` (since there isn't an HTML element with the ID `#op-notices-1`).
4. Take the value gotten in step 3, and look for a property called `getElementsByClassName`. This only works if the value from step 3 is an `object`, like in step 2. Since it *isn't* (it's `null`), it throws this exception and stops everything - nothing further in this entire script runs at all.

So, to solve your issue, you need to check for null between steps 3 and 4. If you insert that step, your code for dealing with "op-notices-1" would now look something like this:

```
var opNotices1 = document.getElementById("op-notices-1");
if (opNotices1 !== null) {
    var list = opNotices1.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].style.display = "none";
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].style.display = "none";
}
```

which simply says "If there is no 'op-notices-1', skip the rest of that bit." (Note that it doesn't make sense to "force it anyway", because `getElementById("op-notices-1")` returning `null` means that there simply isn't any list to do filtering on).

Comment: Thank you very kindly. Yes, my bad on "force it anyway", I didn't know how to phrase that. This has been very helpful - I shall study your explanation. Thank you all!

Comment: @Espskully You're welcome! Note that if an answer definitively solves your problem, you are highly encouraged to click the check mark next to it to accept it.

Comment: My apologies, I'm having a hard time figuring out where the code you provided would go into my existing code. Is this replacing part of the code or in addition to?

Comment: @Espskully This replaces the entire "op-notices-1" bit. You would have a very similar piece of code replacing the "op-notices-2" bit. BTW, I also went and answered your other question, which seems related to this one and may help you out more generally.

Comment: Please disregard, I figured it out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

if the class is not present, `getElementsByClassName` will return `null`. So you can write an `if` statement checking the return value of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Thank you - I was hoping that was the case. I'm just not sure how exactly to write that and where to put it.

Comment: you could use the length attribute on return value of `getElementsByClassName`. For `null` length will be `0`

Comment: I did it for example like this:

                                                                                                                                      
 var status = tablerow.getElementsByClassName('status');
if(status != null) {status[0].innerHTML = "Some Text";} 
So in this case you only have one call of the getElementsByClassName()..
*You can also use if(status.length > 0)